# Nuke command discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.8

Alright, there is something wrong with this code, but I don't understand what.

```
@client.command(aliases=['killchat'])
async def nuke(ctx, amount=9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, channeltwo : ctx.message.channel = None):
   if channeltwo == None:
       await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
   else:
       await ctx.channeltwo.purge(limit=amount)
```

Please, help me I can't understand why module 'ctx' has no attribute 'message'!(That's the error)

Answer (score 0):

Try `ctx.message.author.channel` and there is a limit to what the API allows bots to purge. You won't be able to purge that amount. Also, if the messsages are 2 weeks older or more, you won't be able to purge them either.

Comment: My client is able to purge that amount usual without the following code. Problem is in ```channeltwo : ctx.message.channel = None```

Comment: My point being : use `ctx.message.author.channel` instead of `ctx.message.channel`.

Comment: Codeize, ctx has no attribute message!

Comment: Did you use ```ctx.message.author.channel```?